# c++: tuple with tag-type access

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create a tuple analogue in order to access its elements with the corresponding tag-types, not index. I came up with the next solution (simplified):

```
template<class T> struct tag { using type = T; };
using r = tag<double>;
using t = tag<double>;
using c = tag<int>;
template<class... Ts> class S
{
    std::tuple<typename Ts::type&&...> data;
public:
    S(typename Ts::type&&... args) : data(std::forward<typename Ts::type>(args)...) {}
};
int main()
{
    r::type r0 = 0.;
    const t::type t0 = 1.;
    auto S0 = S<r, t, c>(r0, t0, 2); // <- error here
    //auto T0 = std::forward_as_tuple(r0, t0, 2); // <- works!
}
```

However it doesn't compile (gcc 7.2):

```
error: cannot bind rvalue reference of type ‘tag<double>::type&& {aka double&&}’ to lvalue of type ‘tag<double>::type {aka double}’
 auto S0 = S<r, t, c>(r0, t0, 2);
                               ^
note:   initializing argument 1 of ‘S<Ts>::S(typename Ts::type&& ...) [with Ts = {tag<double>, tag<double>, tag<int>}]’
 S(typename Ts::type&&... args) : data(std::forward<typename Ts::type>(args)...) {}
 ^
```

I found `std::forward_as_tuple` function that can deduce the argument types correctly, so my point is do the same for my class. Any hint what I do wrong?

UPD: initial description was incomplete, sorry. My intention is not storing copies, but references (non-const for non-const arguments and const for const- and rvalue-references, similar to what `std::forward_as_tuple` does). Please, see the comments in the updated code below:

```
template<class... Ts> class S
{
    std::tuple<typename Ts::type...> data;
public:
    template<class... Args>
        S(Args&&... args) : data(std::forward<Args>(args)...) {}
    template<size_t I> auto& get()
    {
        return std::get<I>(data);
    }
};

int main()
{
    r::type r0 = 0.;
    const t::type t0 = 1.;
    auto S0 = S<r, t, c>(r0, t0, 2);
    S0.get<0>() = 111; // <- r0 is not changed!
    S0.get<1>() = 222; // <- must not be possible!

    auto T0 = std::forward_as_tuple(r0, t0, 2);
    std::get<0>(T0) = 333; // <- r0 == 333
    std::get<1>(T0) = 444; // <- compile error -- can't change const!
}
```

Comment: std::tuple akready does it jolly well.

Comment: `typename Ts::type&&` is actually rvalue reference and not forwarding reference.

Comment: @n.m. not exactly -- my goal is to get values by tag-type, not index. tags are distinguishable but actual types are not

Comment: Create an enum that you'll pass to get and use tuple. /* You might use the enum elsewhere. */

Comment: not, this is not an option, @lorro, because not all tags may be used. For example, `auto S1 = S<r, c>(r0, 2); S0.get<c>();` gives an error is c is just a enum member with fixed value 2.

Comment: What I meant, use just std::tuple and std::get; pass an enum value to std::get and done.

Comment: I understand, but it's not possible to use a single enum for tuples with different set of elements.

Comment: Please don't edit answers into your question, post them as an answer instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the solution. The idea is to create an S object using make-function as @VTT suggested. This make-function copies type modifiers (ref, const ref) and added them to the S template parameters. Then, inside S, these type modifiers copied back to the tuple parameters (data) using couple of `conditional_t` templates. `decay_t` is used just to get pure type itself, not reference to it (otherwise compiler, gcc72, says `error: ‘tag<double>&’ is not a class, struct, or union type`; clang38 is a little bit better: `: error: type 'tag<double> &' cannot be used prior to '::' because it has no members`)

```
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>

using namespace std;

// additional parameter is needed to distinguish r and t
template<class T, char c> struct tag { using type = T; };
using r = tag<double, 'r'>;
using t = tag<double, 't'>;
using c = tag<int, 'c'>;
//...

namespace details
{
  template<size_t N, class T, class... Ts>
    struct index_impl {
      static constexpr size_t value = N; };
  template<size_t I, class T, class Ti, class... Ts>
    struct index_impl<I, T, Ti, Ts...> {
      static constexpr size_t value =
        std::is_same<T, Ti>::value? I : index_impl<I + 1, T, Ts...>::value; };

  template<class T, class... Ts>
    struct index {
      static constexpr size_t value = index_impl<0, T, Ts...>::value; };

  template<class T, class... Ts>
    static constexpr size_t index_v = index<T, Ts...>::value;
} // namespace details

template<class... Ts> class S
{
  std::tuple<
    std::conditional_t<
      std::is_reference<Ts>::value,
      std::conditional_t<
        std::is_const<std::remove_reference_t<Ts>>::value,
        const typename std::decay_t<Ts>::type&,
        typename std::decay_t<Ts>::type&
      >,
      typename std::decay_t<Ts>::type
    >...
  > data;
public:
  template<class... Args>
    S(Args&&... args) : data(std::forward<Args>(args)...) {}

  template<class T> auto& get()
  {
    return std::get<details::index_v<T, std::decay_t<Ts>...>>(data);
  }
};

template<class... Ts, class... Args> auto make_S(Args&&... args)
{
  return S<
    std::conditional_t<
      std::is_reference<Args>::value,
      std::conditional_t<
        std::is_const<std::remove_reference_t<Args>>::value,
        const Ts&, Ts&
      >,
      Ts
    >...
  >(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

int main()
{
  r::type r0 = 0;
  const t::type t0 = 1;
  auto S0 = make_S<r, t, c>(r0, t0, 0);
  S0.get<r>() = 111;
  //S0.get<t>() = 222; // <- must not be possible!
  S0.get<c>() = 333;

  auto T0 = std::forward_as_tuple(r0, t0, 2);
  std::get<0>(T0) = 444; // <- r0 == 333
  //std::get<1>(T0) = 555; // <- compile error -- can't change const!
  std::get<2>(T0) = 666;
}
```

I'm sure the idea can be implemented better, however this solution works! For example I'm not quite understand why `is_const` doesn't work with references hence I have to eliminate them from the types using `remove_reference_t`. Thus the final solution is overcomplicated IMO.

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare constructor as a template:

```
#include <utility>
#include <tuple>

template<class T> struct tag { using type = T; };
using r = tag<double>;
using t = tag<double>;
using c = tag<int>;
template<class... Ts> class S
{
    std::tuple<typename Ts::type...> data; // there is no need to use && here as we want tuple to contain items "as is", not references
public:
    template<typename... TArgs>
    S(TArgs && ... args) : data(std::forward<TArgs>(args)...) {}
};
int main()
{
    r::type r0 = 0.;
    const t::type t0 = 1.;
    auto S0 = S<r, t, c>(r0, t0, 2); // <- error here
    static_cast<void>(S0); // not used
    //auto T0 = std::forward_as_tuple(r0, t0, 2); // <- works!
    return(0);
}
```

[Run this code online](https://wandbox.org/permlink/906qYaobKvnRRKwy)

I would like to mention another problem: this kind of tuple won't actually let you access elements by tag type as it allows tag duplication. If you need access by tag type you'll need check tag <-> value type associations more thoroughly. You may also want to check some [existing tagged-tuple implementation](https://github.com/guaranteed-to-be-unique/Tagged-Tuple).

Comment: Simpler and works, thanks, @VTT! However, data stores copies in that case, not references. So it's not the full analogue of `forward_as_tuple` as I expected. Is it even possible without reinventing the whole tuple class?

Comment: @GenaBug This code is not analogue of `forward_as_tuple` at all. First of all `forward_as_tuple` is a function template, not a class template. If you want to store references then you can redefine types used to populate the tuple `using r = tag<double &>;` If you want to covert original types to compatible reference types automatically then you'll need to write a dedicated template function.

Answer (score 0):

`Ts::type&&` is not a forwarding reference, because `Ts::type` is not a template parameter, and as such, the `&&` refer to an rvalue reference. You cannot bind an lvalue to an rvalue reference, hence the error.

`std::forward_as_tuple` works because you are only storing the parameters in a "forwarding tuple", and not storing them in `S`.

Just change them to get `const&` reference, as it can also bind to rvalues as well as to lvalues, if you want to store references (I'll assume you do):

```
template<class... Ts> class S
{
    std::tuple<const typename Ts::type&...> data;
public:
    S(const typename Ts::type&... args) : data(args...) {}
};
```